# non-trivial explode string to collection

Tags: string, powershell, collections, explode

I need a PS function that would take input string and generate output collection as per below:

Input:

```
$someString = "abcd{efg|hijk|lmn|o}pqrs"
```

Desired output:

```
$someCollection = @("abcdefgpqrs","abcdhijkpqrs","abcdlmnpqrs","abcdopqrs")
```

Note: there is going to be at most 1 {...|...|...} expression within the input string; the number of pipes is dynamic and can be anything from 1 to 20 ish.

As I drive the input data, the format of the string to explode does not have to follow exactly the example above; it can be anything else; I am looking for simplicity rather than sophistication.

My question is, is there any RegExp based solution that I could use straight away or should I write my function from the scratch, analysing intput string, detecting all the {s, |s and }s and so on?

Platform: Windows 7 / Windows Server 2012, PowerShell 5.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using PowerShell 5 using regex pretty easily:

```
# define a regex pattern with named groups for all three parts of your string
$pattern = '^(?<pre>[^\{]*)\{(?<exp>.*)\}(?<post>[^\}]*)$'

if($someString -match $pattern){
    # grab the first and last parts
    $prefix = $Matches['pre']
    $postfix = $Matches['post']

    # explode the middle part
    foreach($part in $Matches['exp'] -split '\|'){
        # create a new string for each of the exploded middle parts
        "$prefix$part$postfix"
    }
}
```

Comment: Very elegant and somewhat similar to what I came up with in the meantime:

    `function Explode-String([string] $s) {
        $retVal = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[string]'
        if($s -like '*{*|*}*' -and $s -notlike '*{*|*}*{*|*}*') {
            $chunks = $s -Split{$_ -eq "{" -or $_ -eq "}"} 
            foreach($c in $chunks[1].Split("|")) {
                $retVal.Add($chunks[0]+$c+$chunks[2])
            }
        } else {
            $retVal.Add($s)
        }
        return @(,$retVal)
    }`